# Run shiny app on shiny server installed in docker container from Windows 10 Pro?

Tags: docker, shiny, shiny-server

I am using Windows 10 Pro with Docker installed. I `$ docker pull rocker/shiny` image on my computer and started it as described in documentation https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/shiny/ using the following command:

```
docker run -d -p 80:3838 -v C:\\Users\\<My name>\\Documents\\R\\Rprojects\\ShinyHelloWorld\\:/srv/shiny-server/ -v C:\\Users\\<My name>\\Documents\\R\\Rprojects\\ShinyHelloWorld\\:/var/log/shiny-server/ rocker/shiny
```

The container created successfully:

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
f0ee402966b9        rocker/shiny        "/usr/bin/shiny-serv…"   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:80->3838/tcp   youthful_banach
```

I created ShinyHelloWorld application using RStudio, and the folder on the local host that I mounted to docker container basically contains one file `app.R` with default shiny application created by RStudio.

Now the problem is: I can't run this application from my browser using address `http://localhost:3838/ShinyHelloWorld/`.

When I use URL http://localhost:3838 it returns web page with single sentence `Index of /`. So, there is some one who listens.

Did I correctly run shiny server?

I suppose that I am using incorrect URL in my browser to access server. How to do it correctly?

Do I need some installation of my shiny app to the server?

Is it possible to run shiny server using tocken, like with:
http://localhost:8888/?token=44dab68c1bc7b1662041853573f37cfa03f13d029d397816
as described, e.g. in the book for [COOK, J.: Docker for Data Science: Building Scalable and Extensible Data Infrastructure Around the Jupyter Notebook Server: Apress., 2017](https://www.apress.com/gp/book/9781484230114)

How to find the tocken if it exists?

Suppose that I want to use `docker-compose.yml` and then `$ docker-compose up`. Please, help complete the script below to execute the same command as above.

```
    version:                "3"
    services:
          image:            rocker/shiny
          volumes:
            - C:\\Users\\aabor\\Documents\\R\\Rprojects\\ShinyHelloWorld:/srv/shiny-server/
            - C:\\Users\\aabor\\Documents\\R\\Rprojects\\ShinyHelloWorld:/var/log/shiny-server/
          ports:
            - 80:3838
          container_name:   rocker-shiny-container
```

Comment: On `Windows` with `boot2docker` you need to visit http://192.168.59.103:3838 see [usage](https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/shiny/)

Comment: I do not use `boot2docker` it is not necessary in this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

Look at ports 0.0.0.0:80->3838/tcp - means your port 80 will go to 3838 on the container - so you should try http://localhost first.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by myself. The problem was with folder path.

This command will create docker container correctly:

```
docker run -d -p 3838:3838 -v //c/Users/<My Name>/Documents/R/Rprojects:/srv/shiny-server/ -v //c/Users/<My Name>/Documents/R/Rprojects:/var/log/shiny-server/ rocker/shiny
```

Then if I use URL `http://localhost:3838/ShinyHelloWorld/` in my browser shiny application will start.